# Is it possible to click an anchor link to position a bit further than the anchor on a web page?

Tags: html, css

I want to create an anchor link to a position on the same web page but a bit further than the anchor.

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

```
<div id="contact" class="test">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            Kontakt me today
</div>
```

I would like that after the click the site jumps to the id contact in a way that h2 is further down on the page. Is this possible?

I tried to delete the div's id and place another (empty) div with this id bit more up but then it wasn't precise the location I wanted to be because I had to place the new (empty) div above a picture and then the click resulted the h2 not to be in the desired position.

Comment: Put a div / any element in the position you want to scroll to. Make it's `id` "contact". Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property `scroll-margin-top: [some value here];` and put it on the `#contact` (the id you're using in your href)!